# Update query with entityframework

Tags: entity-framework

How to write an update query in EntityFramework using LINQ to Entities?

EDIT:
And if it is possible how this query can be written in Entity SQL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 2 aternatives:

- Same as Lloyd fetch entity from database, change it's properties and submit changes back into database.
- Write an update statement in a stored procedure, then execute the stored procedure.

Answer (score 3):

LINQ does not support update operation. All you can do is fetch entity from database, change it's properties and submit changes back into database.

Answer (score 2):

Neither LINQ to Entities (nor LINQ to anything else) nor ESQL support updates.